# ng-repeat + array of arrays

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In most cases people use:

```
 $scope.fields = [  
        {name: "name", desc: "its name", required: "yes"},  
        {name: "surname", desc: "its surname", required: ""}
       ];
```

I prefer this type of array:

```
$scope.fields = [  
    ["name", "its name", "required"],  
    ["surname", "its surname", ""]
   ];
```

so I can easy use *splice* function to modify elements.

I created list of input fields like this:

```
<li class="ng-class:item[2]" ng-repeat="field in fields">   
<div>{{field[1]}}: <input type="text" data-ng-model="field[0]" name="field[0]" id="field[0]" /> </div> 
</li>
```

Can anyone explain why input fields are initially filled with name or surname values not empty?

Comment: Because you said that their ngModel is field[0], which is "name" and "surname". You should strive for readability. `field.name` is very readable. Anybody reading the code including yourself in two weeks will understand that it is the name of the field. `field[0]` is not readable at all. Anybody reading the code, including yourself in two weeks, will wonder what `field[0]` is.

Comment: `I prefer this type of array`...  you won't prefer them that way for long and most API's deliver arrays of objects which are far easier to work with

Comment: Thanks people. But how to use splice it first type of array?
For the second I simply use:  $scope.fields[j].splice(2,1,'required')

Comment: You do `$scope.fields[j].required = "yes"` and to remove you can simply do `delete $scope.fields[j].required` you don't need or want to use splice for this as it makes code hard to read

Comment: *Splash!* -the sound of hand clapping a head was heard. Thanx Joao.

Comment: use `splice()` to remove from array, `delete` won't remove index